# Using "it sounds" instead of "it tastes"

Tags: abnormal-psychology

99% of the time I use in the conversation (or when I am thinking) the phrase "it sounds" instead of "it tastes" when I am talking about the food, or drinks, etc.

For example: "This coffee sounds very good.", "I like how this hamburger sounds."

I do not do it intentionally, sometimes I "say" it in my head and then say out loud the "normal" version.

Has this something a name? Or this is probably just my association and there is nothing to it?

EDIT: And recently I have used it in sentence: "I wonder how this will play." (of course it was about the food, but this time I wondered how it will SMELL)

Comment: Generally questions like this are off topic because it refers to a specific person but if it wasn't referring to a person it would be a bit vague or even broad. If the question was narrowed down a bit the question could possibly be answered. You could be talking about a number of things

Comment: So, I am sorry for the OT. Can you help me narrow it down with some additional questions? I know that I do not have a synesthesia. And I do not know how can I be more specific, or if you want, we can move to the private conversation... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Has this something a name?

In general [Speech Errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_error)

In your case (Depends on context and your particulars) it could be considered [semantic substitution](https://books.google.com/books?id=_XXkGml2puUC&pg=PA402&lpg=PA402&dq=word%20exchange%20errors&source=bl&ots=X3GH_9_LGC&sig=7YGOiJv5rApi0woDWCgotUi8Nfw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit746m98rSAhXCrlQKHSU9A4g4ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=word%20exchange%20errors&f=false),(a correct word is substituted with an erroneous but similar word) although verbs seem to be rare and it happens more with nouns. (Hotopf  1980's).